Exception thrown at 0x00007FFECFCBB16B (ucrtbase.dll) in Project-512.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFF9CF4880
I'm trying to read a file in C, but after writing a bunch of code in order to allocate memory I'm having problems actually reading the file in that I'm getting a memory access violation, I tried allocating more memory than I actually need for the char pointer but ultimately I'm still getting the memory allocation error, the code is currently
#include "rendering/Shader.h"
float Vertices[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left 
};
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,   // first triangle
    1, 2, 3    // second triangle
};


unsigned int shaderProgram;
unsigned int VertexBufferObject;
unsigned int VAO;

void compileShaders()
{
    unsigned int vertexShader;
    unsigned int fragmentShader;

    // Vertex Shader
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    char* vertexShaderSource = readShader("shaders\\test\\vertex.glsl");
    printf("Vertex Shader Source:\n%s\n", vertexShaderSource);
    
    if (vertexShaderSource == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Failed to load vertex shader\n");
        return;
    }
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    free(vertexShaderSource);  // Free the shader source after use

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR: VERTEX SHADER FAILED TO COMPILE\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    // Fragment Shader
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    char* fragmentShaderSource = readShader("shaders\\test\\fragment.glsl");
    printf("Fragment Shader Source:\n%s\n", fragmentShaderSource);
    if (fragmentShaderSource == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Failed to load fragment shader\n");
        return;
    }
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    free(fragmentShaderSource);  // Free the shader source after use

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR: FRAGMENT SHADER FAILED TO COMPILE\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    // Shader Program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR: SHADER PROGRAM FAILED TO LINK\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    // Clean up shaders (no longer needed once linked into program)
    free(vertexShaderSource);
    free(fragmentShaderSource);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}


void loadVertexData()
{
    // Generate and bind VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    // Generate and bind VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Set vertex attribute pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Unbind VAO for now
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void loadShaders()
{
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

static char* readShader(char path[]) {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    }
    else {
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
    int lines = 0;
    char full_path[512];
    snprintf(full_path, sizeof(full_path), "%s/%s", cwd, path);
    FILE* fpointer = fopen(full_path, "r");
    if (fpointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: COULD NOT LOAD SHADER");
        return NULL;
    }
    int ch;
    lines++;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fpointer)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            lines++;
            printf("reading line: %d \n", lines);
        }
    }
    printf("there are %d ", lines);
    printf("lines in the file %s\n", path);

    rewind(fpointer);


    fseek(fpointer, 0, SEEK_END);  // Move to the end of the file
    int fileSize = ftell(fpointer);  // Get the size of the file
    rewind(fpointer);
    printf("filesize: %d\n", fileSize);
    char* shaderCode = malloc(fileSize);
    if (shaderCode == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        fclose(fpointer);
        return NULL;
    }
    char* str = malloc(fileSize + 1);
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        fclose(fpointer);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets(str, fileSize, fpointer) != NULL) // fgets() will return NULL on EOF
    {
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    printf("%s", str);

    printf("\n");

    fclose(fpointer);

    printf("Shader loaded successfully. File size: %ld bytes\n", fileSize);
    return shaderCode;
}

with the error happening at
while (fgets(str, fileSize, fpointer) != NULL) 


What is that file that you are reading? It says something about shaders, so I presume it is binary, but you are treating it's content as strings

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

I'm loading a glsl file that's just
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec4 vertexColor; // the input variable from the vertex shader (same name and same type)
void main()
{
FragColor = vertexColor;
}
and if I included ALL my code I think stackoverflow wouldn't allow it

At least specify that it is a text file, as it seems..

I don't see any obvious pointer problems in this function. fgets() should not get an exception as long as str and fpointer are non-NULL and fileSize is not more than the memory that str points to. So I suspect the problem is elsewhere in your program, and it corrupted memory in a way that wasn't noticed until you got here.

Use valgrind and -fsanitize=address to help diagnose this.

What exactly makes you think that the access violation is occurring at the line with the fgets function call? Is that what the debugger told you? Or did you infer this based on the printf output of your program? If you did the latter, then you must take into account that the output is buffered and that the content of the buffer will be lost when an access violation occurs.  This means that it is possible that a printf occurred which you never saw. You can use fflush(stdout); to immediately force any output pending in the buffer to the console.

BTW, your shaderCode is never populated, yet returned from the function. Are you sure the error is where you think it is?

ftell returns long, not int.

I'm using Visual Studio, it stops the program at the point mentioned in the post, so I am pretty sure that's where the error is

updated the post with the other functions in this file

Then put a breakpoint just before it and examine the variables involved. See if anything out of line. Then continue stepping through.

Code has at least these minor problems:
Not sure if fixing these is sufficient, but somethin to get OP started.

Enable all compiler warnings
This will given OP rapid feedback to many of the code weaknesses.
Unchecked return values
Many functions which could return a failure value are not checked.
Off by 1
Given str points to fileSize + 1 bytes, I'd expect fgets() to read likewise.
// while (fgets(str, fileSize, fpointer) != NULL)
while (fgets(str, fileSize + 1, fpointer) != NULL)

Mismatch specifier
Use a specified matching specifier.  (See next point also.)
int fileSize = ftell(fpointer);
...
// printf("Shader loaded successfully. File size: %ld bytes\n", fileSize);
printf("Shader loaded successfully. File size: %d bytes\n", fileSize);

Truncation
int fileSize = ftell(fpointer); can truncate the long return value.  long fileSize = ftell(fpointer); expected.
Line count: off-by-1
If the last line lacks a '\n', the reported count is off-by-1.
Alternate:
    unsigned lines = 0;
    ...
    int ch_previous = '\n';
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fpointer)) != EOF) {
      if (ch_previous == '\n') {
        lines++;
      }
      ch_previous = ch;
    }
    printf("there are %u ", lines);

Do not print on failed read
After the last fgets(str, ...), do not print str.
This is a potential serious bug.
while (fgets(str, fileSize, fpointer) != NULL) {
  printf("%s", str);
}
// printf("%s", str);  // Delete.

Test too late
Following printf() code is undefined behavior (UB) when vertexShaderSource == NULL.  Do test first.
printf("Vertex Shader Source:\n%s\n", vertexShaderSource);
if (vertexShaderSource == NULL) {


Ideas:
Error messages
Suggest error messages use stderr rather than stdout.
Return on error, not continue
When perror("getcwd() error"); occurs, code continues on.  Better to return at this point.
